# set up SSH on Linux to log in with no password

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have set up ssh to login to my remote server with no password using the steps provided in the tutorial at this URL: 
 [SSH Login With no Password](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).

When I try to login to the server using only ssh command:

```
$ ssh user@server.com
```

it works fine, and I am able to login without entering the password but when I try to copy files from local to remote server using scp command:

```
$ scp /location/to/file/localserver user@server:location/whereto/copy
```

it asks me to enter a password which is weird!

I also made sure that all the folders has the correct permissions as explained in the URL above.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host *.*.*.*, user ssadmin, command scp -v -t /home/ssadmin/nexthink_log`

OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to *.*.*.* [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4* compat 0x00000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**
debug1: Host '*.*.*.*' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password

ssadmin@*.*.*.*'s password:
```

Comment: What is the exact command you're using?

Comment: Different users?

Comment: This needs more detail.  What do you mean by 'login... with no password'?  Using asymmetric key authentication?  With or without passphrase?  With or without a key agent?  Or `sshpass`?  Or an `expect` script?  Does your connection depend on your `~/.ssh/config` (if so, post relevant parts), or are all options specified on command line (if so, provide the command line)?

Comment: yes different users

Comment: What i did is configure SSH login without password as this URL: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html ......... without passphrase......no sshpass is used ... this is my command (scp /location/to/file/localserver user@remoteserver:location/whereto/copy)

Comment: when i try (ssh user@remoteserver) it will enter without prompting me to enter a password but when i use (scp /location/to/file/localserver user@remoteserver:location/whereto/copy) this command it will ask me to enter password for user

Comment: and my connection it does not depends on .ssh/config

Comment: @SRoss - what happened when you execute the `scp` using `-B` parameter which should *prevents asking for passwords or passphrases* (i.e. uses `scp -B .....`)?

Comment: @SRoss use scp -v /location/to/file/localserver user@remoteserver:location/whereto/copy to see verbose details and if you couldn't find the reason, put the output here (remove sensetive parts) you can also check /var/log/auth.log on remote server to see more details

Comment: @PHA/Yaron i will check both of suggestions and let you know. thank you

Comment: You have to share the key for each user you want to be able to login as with the given private key.  Have you shared the key with both of those users?

Comment: looks like user@remoteserver doesnt have permission to write to location/whereto/copy - can you ssh in and try and touch a file there?

Comment: @PHA i have used -v with the command and this is what i got

Comment: @SRoss could you check the responses to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/54670/passwordless-ssh-not-working and see if you have the permission issue?

Answer (score 1):

First login into your linux pc and generate a pair of public keys using following command.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

When it asks for a password just hit enter.

create a .ssh folder in your server user and in it,
upload new generated public key (id_rsa.pub) on your PC  under your user's .ssh directory as a file name authorized_keys.

Set the permissions:

```
$ ssh user@server.com "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

And that's it!

Secure Passwordless login.

Comment: hi, thank you for your response, I already done all of that, and when i run $ ssh user@server.com ... am able to enter with no password, my issue happens when i try to copy files using "scp" from the local to the remote server, once i type in the command it ask me for the password

Comment: @SRoss just press enter again and see what happens.

Comment: what do u mean press enter again, when ? if you mean after it ask me for password, then pressing enter will give me permission denied please try again and ask me for the password again

Comment: @SRoss did you give a blank password while creating the SSH keys?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ssh-copy-id` command

> $ ssh-copy-id user@hostname

This will simply add your local keys to the `authorized_keys` file in the remote server. Make sure you are able to use authorized keys by enabling it in `sshd_config` file. This way you will never be prompted for password neither in `ssh` or in `scp`.

Comment: I did and it gives me "All keys were skipped because they are already exist on the remote system"

Answer (score 0):

When you put in the password the secure copy works?

If you get permissions denied, it may just be the location you are trying to copy to doesn't allow writes by the remote user.